# GraphChi input data file

Tags: graphchi

I have downloaded GraphChi package and wanted to run the example programs.
I am using Java version of the GraphChi.
The input for the GraphChi are EdgeListFormat or AdjacencyListFormat.

If any one has successfully ran the example programs, please let me know how to get the EdgeListFormat or AdjacencyListFormat files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipage http://code.google.com/p/graphchi/wiki/ExampleApps contains links to two such graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I used the livejournal dataset algorithm from [here](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-LiveJournal1.html) which is in the edgelist format with the pagerank algorithm and it worked well for me.

The key is that you need to provide a numeric id for each vertex (which is documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/graphchi/wiki/EdgeListFormat) but I did not pay attention to it)

I wasn't able to download the twitter graph, there seems to be a problem with the server, but I'll be trying that next.